# pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint') after changing the python mysql connector

Tags: python-3.x, upgrade, pymysql

I was getting the below error after changing the python mysql connector from **MYSQL-python** to **PyMySQL**. I had to change my connector because I upgraded my python version from 2.7 to 3.4 and MYSQL-python is not compatible with python3

```
    sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) 
(1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint') 
[SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE crpt_metric (\n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \n\towner_id BIGINT NOT NULL, \n\tname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, \n\tmtype VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, \n\tdtype VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, \n\taggr_func VARCHAR(10), \n\tis_deleted BOOL, \n\tdw_column_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id), \n\tCONSTRAINT fk_crpt_metric_owner_id FOREIGN KEY(owner_id) REFERENCES crpt_owner (id), \n\tCHECK (is_deleted IN (0, 1))\n)\n\n']
```

Any help would be appreciated.